# Status 200, but JSP in Spring only displaying un-rendered code

Tags: spring, jsp

Although my index.jsp opens in a browser with a Status 200 it only displays the JSP code.

I've read through what seem to be all related issues/solutions on this site, but none of the solutions have worked. e.g. adding jstl, jasper, etc. jars into my pom.xml and build path; mapping variations like "/", "/*", etc. No errors in the Spring log- just that JSPs aren't rendering or being "seen" as JSPs. My newest theories are that something is over-writing or conflicting, or that Spring needs something to "see" JSPs under the WEB-INF folder, but it's not easy to debug. Seems a stupid thing that a JSP doesn't render, so any insight would be helpful.

AppConfig

```
package mil.dfas.springmvc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

/**
 * @author David Higgins
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mil.dfas.springmvc.controller"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

LMSInitializer

```
package mil.dfas.springmvc.config;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import mil.dfas.filters.LoginFilter;
import mil.dfas.filters.TimeoutFilter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 * The Spring MVC DispatcherServlet needs to be declared and mapped for all request processing.
 * In a Servlet 3.0+ environment, AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class is used to register and initialize the DispatcherServlet programmatically.
 * 
 * @author $Author: David Higgins $
 * @version $Revision: 1.0 $ $Date: 2019/05/12 $
 */

public class LMSInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LMSInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        FilterRegistration timeoutFilter = servletContext.addFilter("timeoutFilter", new TimeoutFilter());
        timeoutFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "*.do");

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        LOGGER.info("LMSInitializer: Configuring Servlet Filters" );
        LoginFilter loginFilter = new LoginFilter();
        return new Filter[] {new LoginFilter()};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class <?> [] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class <?> [] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

LMSController

```
package mil.dfas.springmvc.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * @author David Higgins
 */
@Controller
public class LMSSpringController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView forward(Model model) {
        System.out.println("LMS Controller");

        model.addAttribute("msg","Forward Handled");

        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

No error messages. JSPs just don't displays as JSPs.

The problem must be something with the pom.xml. It must be a conflict with dependencies. I've added jasper, jstl, and others, but no change. Status 200 and no log errors, but no jsp rendering.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version> <!-- 2.1.5.RELEASE ? -->
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>mil.dfas.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeDevelopment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId> 
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- I think maybe including servlet dependencies is forcing servlet version 
            to 4.0 since no versions are included, so Spring Boot parent will provide 
            the defaults and maybe force latest version (?) A lot of this servlet stuff 
            should already be included in Tomcat bin (on build path) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.keypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>png-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- As Oracle JDBC drivers are not in public Maven repositories (legal 
            reasons) downloading the jar was the best available option. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added 5/17/19 DJM, may want to get directly from Maven repo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> <configuration> <source>1.8</source> 
                    <target>1.8</target> </configuration> -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: post your jsp page

Comment: try with   public String forward(Model model) {.... return "index";}

Comment: Not much to the index.jsp: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:if test='${empty Validated}'><jsp:forward page="/do/Index" /></c:if>

Comment: Sadly, switching to "public Spring", etc. caused a 404 error. -Not sure if it helps, but the code parts I've posted per this JSP problem is part of a migration from Struts 1x to Spring 5. I've tried to keep as much of the original code as is to minimize complexity. Once the Spring iteration is working I'll look to make additional upgrades.

Comment: @DavidHiggins Could you post the o/p of the index page. And `jsp:forward` should render the page under `WEB-INF/views` and you have given `do/Index` So try to render a different page under  WEB-INF/views like `<jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/views/test.jsp" /></c:if>`

Comment: Well, a good thought. Substituting "/WEB-INF/..." seems to work the same as the "do'Index" though. The problem is that the JSP (both on the index.jsp (and the banner.jsp page that precedes index.jsp as part of a user validation check) display the respective raw JSP code). Banner.jsp properly displays its HTML part normally in the browser, but also displays the associated "<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>" part. Creating a new Dynamic Web Project with a simple test xxx.jsp works fine.

Comment: I had thought my web.xml might have been the culprit as it included "*.jsp" and not something like "/"- "<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>spring</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>" The "*.jsp" at least allows for the banner.jsp and index.jsp pages to come up in a browser (just with no JSP parsing). Using "/" throws an immediate 404 error.

Comment: Although I never solved this jsp problem I ended up getting a work-a-round to do what I needed using Thymeleaf.